# Need guidance with Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with one of my current tasks wherein i am trying to pick only the table names from the query via Python

So basically lets say a query looks like this

```
Create table a.dummy_table1
as
select a.dummycolumn1,a.dummycolumn2,a.dummycolumn3 from dual

Now i am passing this query into Python using STRINGIO and then reading only the strings where it starts with "a" and has "_" in it like below
table_list = set(re.findall(r'\ba\.\w+', str(data)))

Here data is the dataframe in which i have parsed the query using StringIO

now in table_list i am getting the below output

a.dummy_table1
a.dummycolumn1
a.dummycolumn2


whereas the Expected output should have been like 
a.dummy_table1
```

<Let me know how we can get this done , have tried the above regular expression but that is not working properly>

**Any help on same would be highly appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current regex string r"\ba.\w+" simply matches any string which:

1. Begins with "a" (the "\ba" part)
2. Followed by a period (the "." part)
3. Followed by 1 or more alphanumeric characters (the "\w+" part).

If I've understood your problem correctly, you are looking to extract from str(data) any string fragments which match this pattern instead:

1. Begins with "a"
2. Followed by a period
3. Followed by 1 or more alphanumeric characters
4. Followed by an underscore
5. Followed by 1 or more alphanumeric characters

Thus, the regular expression should have "_\w+" added to the end to match criteria 4 and 5:

```py
table_list = set(re.findall(r"\ba\.\w+_\w+", str(data)))
```

Comment: Hi Aidan ,

Many thanks , this solution works like a charm . 

I was also able to do this by passing the output then to a re.search call as below 

if re.search('\w+[!@_#$%*()]+', str(i)) or re.search('[!@_#$%*()]+\w+', str(i)):

In this i filtered out any strings which was not having atleast one special character and got it working for me 

But your solution is a much better approach than mine , so thank you again for helping out on this , appreciate it